# Prove that $E(\sqrt{X})\leq\sqrt{EY}$

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X > 0$ and $Y > 0$ are random variables such that $E(X/Y) ≤ 1$. Prove that
$E(\sqrt{X})\leq\sqrt{EY}$

Note: Here X/Y is X divided by Y .

Since I don't know whether X and Y are independent so I cannot separate them from E(X/Y). How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $\sqrt{X}$ as $\sqrt{X/Y}\cdot\sqrt{Y}$ and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to obtain the result.

Comment: How can you show that $\sqrt{X}$ is a vector space? I mean, how to prove the third property of vector space: $\sqrt{X}+ \sqrt{Y}\geq\sqrt{X+Y}$

Comment: Well, $(\sqrt{X} + \sqrt{Y})^2 = X + Y + 2\sqrt{XY} \ge X + Y$, so taking square roots results in $\sqrt{X} + \sqrt{Y} \ge \sqrt{X + Y}$.